# and so on (and so forth) repeated in OALD

Tags: idioms

I was reading Idioms for the word "forth" on OALD (Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary) and I faced this:

[image]

As you can see in the image They put phrases. first one is "and so forth" and second one is "and so on (and so forth)".

I don't understand why they repeat "and so forth" in the parentheses for the second one. what do they mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiom in full is **“and so on and so forth”**.

Since you searched for “forth”, the part of the idiom that has that, will be emphasised.

You can use **“and so on”** on its own. If you wish to emphasise how incredibly long something is, you can add **”and so forth”**.

> The teacher kept droning on, it was a shopping list of complaints.
> Pants were too low, hairstyles were too long, and so on, and so forth.

Here the usage indicates a *long list* of complaints.

Answer (score 1):

That repetition you see is because **and so forth** is actually the sub-heading. Whereas **and so on (and so forth)** is the actual idiom where it appears as a sub-part.

I guess you are looking into a physical paperback/hardcover copy, hence you see it on the same line. If you check it online, it appears as follows:

[image: image describing the meaning as found in the online OALD]

As already said in the accepted answer, **and so on** can be used as a stand-alone idiom, it can also be used along with **and so forth** to put special emphasis on the never-ending something (requests, lists, pleas, complaints, etc).